# Can't get 2-relay module to work through JD-Vcc

Tags: switches, relay, 5v, module

I bought this 2-relay module: https://www.amazon.de/gp/product/B00E0NTPP4/ref=ppx_yo_dt_b_search_asin_title?ie=UTF8&psc=1

I'm testing it out using a 5v 1 amp power supply.

If the JD-Vcc jumper is set and I power the relay board via the Vcc and ground pins next to the input pins, everything works fine. When I pull an input pin to ground, the relay actuates.

Anyway, I want to power the relay board through JD-Vcc. Here, I can't get anything to work. I removed the JD-Vcc jumper and connected the power supply's 5v to the JDVcc pin and ground to the ground pin on the separate connector set. If I touch the input pins to ground of the power supply, the relays don't actuate.

I've searched through a few posts her and I can't see what I'm missing. Any clues out there?

Comment: Have you seen this JD-Vcc Q&A? https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/505318/how-to-properly-use-a-relay-module-with-jd-vcc-from-arduino-raspberry

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to connect power to both JD and Vcc.  By removing the jumper you are only powering one side.

Comment: Thanks, evildemonic! That's exactly it. It's working now. And do I need to connect ground on the input connector set?

Comment: The ground should be common across both sides, so no.  You could verify this with an ohm meter.