# How can I test a TLP582 optocoupler?

Tags: power-electronics, opto-isolator, optoelectronics

Have few of these components (TLP582) and I need to design a test circuit to test its functionality.

[Datasheet of TLP582](https://datasheetspdf.com/pdf-file/517550/Toshiba/TLP582/1)

I have no idea how to make a circuit for this.

What should I be testing in an optocoupler?

Comment: "Testing its functionality" is a rather broad range, and so the testing circuitry could be very simple or rather elaborate. The simplest circuit that I can think of would be a voltage supply, resistor and switch activating the input side, and (together with the voltage supply) a resistor and LED on the output side. Closing the switch would, if things are set up properly, activate the LED on the output side. If that is all you are interested in, I could give you a circuit diagram. But perhaps you want more?

Comment: There are two test circuits in the data sheet.

Comment: #Axel Blaze, @Math Keeps Me Busy's LED test is good for newbie projects. For ninja projects like mine, I usually test with an application in mind, eg (1) Logic level = 3V3/5V0, (2) operating frequency = 10Hz (Note 1), (3) Operating current If = 5mA (Note 2) , (4) Arduino, Rpi, or NE555 oscillator.  I usually start with NE555, set frequency = 1Hz/10Hz/100Hz and see if LED blinks. Note 1 -  For simple relay circuits, 1 to 10 Hz is goo enough, because toy relays cannot toggle faster that 10Hz. Note 2 - you need to to decide the If from typical 5mA to max 20 mA. Higher frequencies need a scope.

Comment: #Math Keeps Me Busy thank you for the info just having another doubt generally to determine a optocoupler is good/faulty what parameter must be determined or checked based on that can you suggest a circuit.

Comment: @tlfong01 Thank you for the procedure can you show me a circuit diagram for it so i can understand it better please

Comment: #Axel Blaze, Ah, let me see if I can suggest something. You might like to try to read some examples first (Note 1), then I can try to search my junk box for (1) TLP582 optocoupler, (2)  bare bone relay switches (not modules), (3) NE555 timer/oscillators. Please let me know a little more of your electronics background, eg. do you know (a) how to use a multi-meter to measure voltage, current, and resistance, (b) how to use Arduino C++ or Rp python to blink a LED, ... Chheers.

Comment: Note 1 - My answer to the following relay question: 
How can I increase the output current to make it sufficient for relay module? 
https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/527190/how-can-i-increase-the-output-current-to-make-it-sufficient-for-relay-module/527304#527304  shows how to design an optocoupler for a relay circuit, with detailed calculation on the current and voltage. There is also a reference where you can find more relay circuit examples, and spec/datasheets of bare bone relays, and optocouplers.  / to continue, ...

Comment: I am not using TLP582, perhaps I need to read the datasheet and see my examples using EL817C is also useful for TL582. Please feel free to make newbie comments or counter suggestions.

Comment: @tlfong01  Yes I can use a multimeter and have worked on few simple arduino projects I did go through  electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/527190/ but will it work on TLP582 ?

Comment: @Axel Blaze, You knowledge and skills is perfect for my potential answer, which I assume readers to my answer have only a little bit of experience in using optocouplers and relays.

Comment: Now I am going away to search my junk box the real components to do our optocoupler experiment. I will also start reading the TLP582 datasheet. Ah, lock down afternoon tea time. See you later. Cheers.

Comment: @Axel Blaze, Just some quick updates. (1) I skimmed the TLP582 datasheet and found its input side is simple and similar to the popular optocoupler EL817C. (2)  However TLP582's output is Totem Pole, while EL817C is open collector.  Each kind of output has pros and cons. (3) There is 90% chance that the circuits from the two answers I mentioned for EL817C can easily be modified for TLP582. (4) I found the following in my junk box: (a) EL817C, (b) TLP5214, whch is similar to TLP582 with totem pole output. Unfortunately I did not find any TLP582. / to continue, ...

Comment: (c) A couple of bare bone relay switches.  You might like to skimmed through the datasheets of TLP582, TLP5214, and EL817C, and let me know which of the three you prefer.  Cheers.

Comment: @tlfong01 Yes I went through the datasheets of TLP5214, EL817C and TLP582. TLP5214 is the next similar one in the list so that would be my choice.

Comment: @Axel Blaze, Thank you for your reply. So I would suggest to start with your first choice - TLP5214.  Actually when I asked you to make the choice, I was expecting you to choose TLP582 or TLP5214. I guessed you might tell me that you have many TLP582s in your place where TLP582 is the standard, or your project supervisor specifies TLP582. Or you have a tight deadline, then I would agree with TLP582.  Now if you don't have any particular reason to insist on TLP582, then TLP5214 seems to be the first/best choice, for the following reasons.  / to continue, ...

Comment: (1) If you have no problem getting a TLP5214 through hole chip, or SMD module (I found both lying in my junk box, collecting dust for a couple of years!), then we can do pairing experiment/learning in two differents parts of the world, perhaps in different time zones.  (2) If we have completed learning TLP512, you might like to repeated our joint TLP5214 experiemtn using TP582, working on your own, which I think is the best way to learn by problem solving and case studies. / to continue, ...

Comment: I forgot to mention that there is yet one more optocoupler we can consider, that it ***EL354***, mentioned in my other post: How to properly use a relay module with JD-VCC from Arduino/Raspberry? - RpiSE, 2020jun13, 3k times
https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/505318/how-to-properly-use-a-relay-module-with-jd-vcc-from-arduino-raspberry. EL354 is not that popular, and I don't have it in hand, so  not a good choice.  Anyway, you might like to tell me other brainstorming ideas such as your preferred deadline, before I start reading the TLP5214 datasheet.  Tea time, see you later.

Comment: @tlfong01 Corrections TLP582 is better to start apologies for mentioning TLP5214. I got more 5 days as the deadline. Too much going on and in a baffled state , I would  love to try TLP5214 next in the list.

Comment: No problem. Perhaps I can try TLP582 first. Please let me know if you have a through hole chip or a assembled module. It would be nice to give me a link or a photo. Cheers.

Comment: @tlfong01 Yes here is the link https://datasheetspdf.com/pdf-file/517550/Toshiba/TLP582/1 2. Regarding image it looks the same as the one in datasheet. https://www.google.com/imgres?imgurl=https%3A%2F%2F5.imimg.com%2Fdata5%2FSN%2FMS%2FFB%2FSELLER-5304454%2Ftransistor-inverter-500x500.jpg&imgrefurl=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.indiamart.com%2Fproddetail%2Ftransistor-inverter-13284200897.html&tbnid=H9C03TfR8P9tIM&vet=12ahUKEwidqsPrh4zuAhXTQX0KHeiIC2UQMygDegQIARA0..i&docid=oljfsd5C465BBM&w=500&h=434&q=Images%20for%20TLP%20582&hl=en&ved=2ahUKEwidqsPrh4zuAhXTQX0KHeiIC2UQMygDegQIARA0

Comment: @Axel Blaze, The datasheet is good. Now one more thing - What do you mean to "test" the optocoupler? Do you just need to show (a) if you can blink a LED, by hand, using a jumper to connect the optocoupler's input to a 1.5V battery? Or (b) Use NE555 oscillator as input instead of a battery or jumper wire? Or (c) Trigger a relay. Or (d) Must use Arduino code?

Comment: @tffong01 hi thank you soo much by the way do you have any idea how to test signal isolation amplifiers as well ? like the ISO106

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***Question***

*How can I test a TLP582 optocoupler?*

---

***Answer***

*Part A - Short Answer*

TLP582 is similar to the popular ELP817C, except the following:

1. *TLP582 has Totem Pole output, so can either source or sink current.  ELP817C other other hand, can only sink current*.
2. *TLP582 has Schmitt trigger inverter in the input, while EL817C has none (not very sure)
   TLP 582 can be biased similar to EL817C, as described in References 1 and 2 below.*

---

Procedures to testing TLP582

[image: EL817C/TLP521-4 Testing Procedure]

---

[*YouTube Video of TLP521-4 Testing, Using NE555 oscillator as input to blink a LED*](https://youtu.be/AfboBjkdHYo)

---

1. *To blink a LED*

   (a) Connect one end of 1kΩ resistor to 5V

   (b) Connect the other end of resistor to TLP582 Input LED　Pin 1

   (c) Connect Ground to TLP582 Pin 2 to Ground

   (d) Connect one end of another 1kΩ resistor to TLP582 Output (Pin 4)

   (e) Connect ...

*Note 1*

I would suggest the OP to complete my circuit design, and also draw a schematic, showing the current calculations, as what is done in the EL817C in AppendixB. :)

*Note 2*

All the test procedures and calculations have not been proofread.

*Warning*

I am just a friendly hobbyist.  *No guarantee no nothing won't melt down or blow up.*

---

2. *To switch a relay*

Appendix B show how an EL817C optocoupler is used to switch a relay. TLp582 can be use the same circuit to switch a relay.  However, there is one complication: EL817C output is open collector, so it can only be used to sink current, or Low level triggered at the front end.  On the other hand, TLP582's output is is Totem Pole (Push Pull) output, so can be used to do either High or Low level triggering.

---

***Part B - Long Answer***

1. */ to continue, ...*

---

***References***

(1) [How can I increase the output current to make it sufficient for relay module?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/527190/how-can-i-increase-the-output-current-to-make-it-sufficient-for-relay-module)

(2) [How to properly use a relay module with JD-VCC from Arduino/Raspberry?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/505318/how-to-properly-use-a-relay-module-with-jd-vcc-from-arduino-raspberry)

(3) [Push–pull (Totem Pole) Output - Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Push%E2%80%93pull_output)

(4) [Schmitt Trigger - Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schmitt_trigger)

---

***Appendices***

*Appendix A - TLP582 Datsheet Summary*

[image: tlp582 summary 1]

[image: tlp582 summary 2]

[image: tlp582 summary 3]

---

*Appendix B - EL817C and EL354 Datasheet Summary*

[image: EL817c el354 summary]

---

*Appendix C -TLP521-4 Datasheet Summary*

[image: tlp521-4 summary 1]

[image: tlp521-4 summary 2]

---

*Appendix D - Switching a relay using EL817C*

[image: el817c example]

---

*Appendix E - TLP582 Test Suggestion*

Note: I don't have TLP582 to experiment with.  So I am only suggesting the OP to do (1) Switch on/off a LED, (2) Blink a LED using manual jumpers, NE555 oscillator, or Arduino/Rpi C++/Python programming.  I am updating Appendix E below to show how to do it using TLP512-4 or ELK817C.

[image: TLP582 Test Suggestion]

---

*Appendix E - Using manual jumper wire as input to switch on/off LED for both TLP512-4 (Channel 1), and Sharp PC817C*

*Notes:*

1. Both input logic power supply and output power supplied are 5V, with common ground.
2. Input series current limiting/protecting resistor is 1kΩ, current passing through input IR LED is around 4mA.
3. Output example load is 1kΩ in series with a LED (Common Cathode to Ground)

The wiring diagram is given below. A schematic might come later. :)

[image: tlp512-4 and EL817C test]

---