# Need help finding inputs and outputs of a relay

Tags: relay

I have here the diagram of a table for a 9-1415389-1 relay.

The mechanics of the relay I understand for the most parts, however I need an in-deph explanation of the inputs outputs;

What is A1, A2, 11, 12, 14? what goes into it and what goes out of it?

[image]

Comment: It is very important to ***use a flyback diode to protect your driving transistors*** from back EMF. You can find (1) Relay characteristics, (2) Relay wiring diagrams in the following Q&A: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/505318/how-to-properly-use-a-relay-module-with-jd-vcc-from-arduino-raspberry. Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

A1 and A2 are the relay coil (the input).  The other terminals are the contacts ("output")

Terminal 11 is the common/moving contact, 12 is Normally Closed, and 14 is Normally Open.  Relays are normally drawn with the contacts in the "not operated" position.