# Open Collector Output connection to a relay

Tags: relay, open-collector

Hey sorry if this question is too simple, as i am not an expert in this.

I have a device ( industrial router, works at 0- 30vdc) which has a Galvanically isolated Open collector ( External 0-30 VDC, 0.25A ) and the GND. I also have OC output ( External VCC 0-30 VDC ). These OC outputs can be remotely switched on and off using http . I need to attach a relay to this connections so that I can power up big flood lights ( 300 W ) on and off . Can the this flood lights be powered up by any chance ?

Comment: Your question is not clear. Please post photos or a schematic of what you have. I suspect the answer is yes. Connect 12V to one side of relay coil and other side of relay coil to the open connector. Relay coil needs to be rated for less than 30V. The open collector is most likely provided exactly for this. But I am not sure because your question is not clear.

Comment: A relay with a coil rating to suit available power supply and contacts rated for the 300W (AC presumably?) load will be available.

More details will help.  
AC lights?

Comment: No lights are powered through DC.

Comment: @JoelCherian  SO you need MUCH better information. What TDC for lights? At 30V that's 10A (per light?) and well above the 0.25A mentioned. FULL description please. Relays ARE available. Can also be done fully solid stae but specs MUST be provided.

Comment: Tungsten lights draw 10x power when cold

Comment: Ah, let me see. If your device has the following switching device: “***Open collector ( External 0-30 VDC, 0.25A)***”, then it should be able to switch another device, in your case, a relay module, whose input accepts open collector output of another device.  Your spec of 0-30DC is not very clear, if it can pull down the input of a say 5V relay module, then it should be 90% OK. You might like to read the following Q&A for more details: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/505318/how-to-properly-use-a-relay-module-with-jd-vcc-from-arduino-raspberry. Good luck. Cheers.

Comment: If you have not yet bought your relay, I would recommend (1) the JD-Vcc type which is optoisolated, therefore more safe, and (2) Vcc jumper select, which is more flexible for 3V3 or 5V0 MCU/SBC.