# OPTOCOUPLER EL817S1 OUTPUT 24V

Tags: opto-isolator

is it possible optocoupler EL817 wiht input 3.3VDC and output 24VDC like below circuit.
and if it possible what is the suitable value for the resistor

[image]

Comment: 1. EL817 output is not strong enough to directly drive a buzzer. The usual trick is to first drive a BJT which is strong enough to in turn to drive a relay switch (or a buzzer). You might like to skim the following post to get a rough idea on the EL817C/NPN BJT biasing design. 2. If you are going to use a BJT for EL817C, you might like to show your circuit so everybody can help. Cheers. Ref: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/505318/how-to-properly-use-a-relay-module-with-jd-vcc-from-arduino-raspberry.

Comment: Why would a buzzer  need opto-isolation and what current is this?

Comment: please stop shouting.

Comment: @tlfong01 okey i will upload full schematic after it finish.

Comment: @TonyStewartEE75 in this case i want to switch on the buzzer by give 24VDC

Comment: If you have a 3V3 signal, say, from a GPIO pin, you can directly drive an active buzzer (Eg, using 4k7 for the front end BJT,, without using any optocoupler. There is also a demo program to beep the buzzer.) Reference: Active Piezo Buzzer Makes Sound On Both Rpi GPIO Low and High Level Signal Asked 2 years, 3 months ago Viewed 3k times. 
https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/97980/active-piezo-buzzer-makes-sound-on-both-rpi-gpio-low-and-high-level-signal.

Comment: 24Vdc is not a current and buzzers if plastic insulated do not need opto isolation

Comment: @TonyStewartEE75 sorry buzzer spec is : 20mA 24VDC