# 4-channel 5V relay module power supply

Tags: arduino, power-supply, relay

I am working on home vertical growing project.

**INTRO**

I am using:

- Power supply 12V 20A (https://www.aliexpress.com/item/32983648084.html?spm=a2g0s.9042311.0.0.3af34c4d5hRuZn)
- Voltage regulator L7805CV (https://datasheet.octopart.com/L7805CV-STMicroelectronics-datasheet-7264666.pdf)
- 4-channel relay module (https://www.handsontec.com/dataspecs/4Ch-relay.pdf)
- Arduino 2560 Mega

Below is my wiring diagram (it is not the nicest, but I don't know what programs are you using for better drawings).
There is not shown, but those "INx" signals from relay module are connected to arduino digital pins. In total there will be 6 relay modules.

[image: Schematics]

So the relay model datasheet says each channel needs 15-20mA that is 60-80mA per module.
[image: relay_characteristics]

And L7805CV can deliver from 5mA to 1A.
[image: L7805CV electrical characteristics]

**PROBLEM**

At first I was supplying 3 modules with only 1 L7805CV, but when I tried controlling modules only one relay clicked, but the leds were lit up for all of them but they were dimed. At this point there was no Arduino connected I was using only one wire and connecting it to 5V or GND, controlling one relay at a time.

So I thought it was problem with power supplying, and added one L7805CV for each relay module. And now sometimes they "click", sometimes they don't and sometimes they are "clicking" like crazy while control signal is not changing. And sometimes there are some wired buzzing sounds.

Are there any suggestions?

Thanks in advance for all the answers.

Comment: The link for the power supply does not work. Is the jumper on the relay board removed or connected? Either way the relays should not be randomly clicking, no matter what.

Comment: (1) The spec of 15-20mA driving current is WRONG. Actually your Arduino/Rpi GPIO pin needs only around 5mA to drive each channel's optocoupler (EL817C), but then you need 50 mA to 70mA to switch on blue Songle relay switch (not the module, see Part C of my answer to the following referred Q&A) (2) Ref: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/505318/how-to-properly-use-a-relay-module-with-jd-vcc-from-arduino-raspberry, (3) L7805 series regulator is not a good choice. I would recommend a switching PSU module, such as the cheapy L2596 module,

Comment: @Justme Jumper is removed.

Comment: @tlfong01 I will check your answer. Is L7805 not good because of the voltage drop on it? I have a plan to change it in the future for some other switching regulator, probably L2596 as you suggested. I just had some L7805 laying around so I can start testing other parts of the system.

Comment: Did you applied heatsink for 7805? It has internal thermal protection. From 12V to 5V, 1A , 7W should be dissipated. Without heatsink it can dissipate 0.35W or less, depends on environment.

Comment: @user263983 Thanks for pointing that out. There are no heatsinks applied at the moment. This is just for quick testing purposes and I am going to change L7805 for a switching power supply as was sudgested by tlfong01.

Comment: @tlfong01 Thanks for your comment it is realy helpful for understanding how these modules work. I maneged to fix my problem with capacitors, but will definetly go for switching power supply in the future.

Comment: @ves_el, yes, L7805 and other series voltage regulators, comparing to switching ones, generate too much heat, so are environmental unfriendly.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation between *ves_el* and *tlfong01* has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/131309/discussion-on-question-by-ves-el-4-channel-5v-relay-module-power-supply). Please continue any discussion there. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You haven't drawn any capacitors on your diagram. A 7805 needs them on the input and output, as shown in the data sheet. Without them, the output of the regulator can be unstable.

Comment: Thanks for the heads up, I will add them and report how it went.

Comment: I added capacitors to input and output of L7805 and now relays are acting normal. Regulator unstabiliti explains why relays were clicking randomly.

Comment: So that is he issue. 50 mA you can get without overheating. Also relay coil 5V you may feed from 12V with resistor in series.