# Controlling Relay using ESP8266 Module

Tags: circuit-analysis, relay, esp8266

I have 5 such relays attached to an ESP-12E module with a 600ma Power Supply. The LED (LED4) glows but the relay doesn't switch. Is there anything wrong with my schematic?

Using MMBT3904 instead of a BC848B and using a 5V sugar cube relay.

[image]

Comment: Is the relay very "low voltage" and "low current" ? I think you would drive it separately (or in parallel with the diode-R14, from emitter to ground), because of the 2k2 emitter resistor (too high), unless the relay needs very low current.

Comment: Should I try 1k for the emitter resistor?

Comment: Its a 5V relay not really low current. This is the relay - https://mbatechmeds.com/wp-content/uploads/2021/07/5V-SPDT-Relay-1.jpg

Comment: Put the LED+dropper resistor in parallell with the relay coil, not in series.

Comment: This relay need at least 70-100 mA, don't remember.

Comment: Yes, 70mA. See Part C of the answer to this Q&A: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/505318/how-to-properly-use-a-relay-module-with-jd-vcc-from-arduino-raspberry

Comment: In parallel like this - https://imgur.com/RGhlz00

Comment: Ok 70-80 ma so for 5 relays + 6 LEDs I think it would exceed 600ma power supply that I have.

Comment: *it would exceed 600ma power supply that I have.* Then use a supply that can deliver more current **or** make sure not all the relays are energized at once (it depends on your application if that is a valid option) **or** use relays which need less current.

Comment: yes I have removed 4 relays and removed the LED and resistor for the one relay I have kept in the pcb. Now I will test whether that single relay will work.

Comment: NPN - emitter goes to ground for switching.  PNP - emitter goes to VCC for switching.

Comment: Just to update : removed all the LEDs and changed all the base Resistors to 75 ohms, all relays switching now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For comparison, as you have a drive of 3.3V max, see the difference of the relay current.

Circuit 1 (left) is not really "the good choice".

[image]

Here for a drive of 5V.

[image]

Comment: Your "circuit 1"  does not correspond to what OP shows as there the relay is in series with the collector of the NPN. In this "circuit 1" the NPN acts as a **emitter follower** and at its emitter the voltage will not be higher than 3.3 V - Vbe = 2.7 V which is not enough to engage the relay, the relay needs 5 V. Your "circuit 2" does that though.

Comment: You are right. I was only proposing the left circuit to show that it was not a good idea to place the relay parallel to the Led-R ... since the 3.3V output could not have injected the desired current anyway. This would be different if the driving output was 5V.

Comment: I update my answer with a driving of 5V

Comment: *I update my answer with a driving of 5V* Unfortunately, OP is using an ESP module, which can only run on 3.3 V, not 5 V.

Comment: @Bimpelrekkie Right, but only for comparing results ... for other "new designs", and "informed choice" ? Note that "circuit 1" is in red color ..., saying "not good choice". :-)

Answer (score 10):

Here's what your schematic is (left) and what I would use (right):

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fXnS6u.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

The left schematic will act like a (sort of) **current source**, where the **transistor** will determine the current. Here, that current is **too low** for the relay to engage.

In the right circuit, the transistor will act as a **switch**. The current will be determined by the **relay**. The LED (D3) and resistor (R4) are optional, leave them out if you do not need them.

Answer (score 0):

Because the title is "controlling relay using ESP8266" rather that "what's wrong with the way I'm driving this relay" I'm going to suggest the use of prefab relay modules with driver circuitry based around optocouplers.

Here's an example on ebay for about ten bucks. https://www.ebay.com.au/itm/164378054696

I have no affiliation with the seller other than having bought some relay modules.

The design is an excellent solution which is why it's super common and cheap as chips pre-fab. The input impedances are very high and the trigger current can be as low as microamps although the unit shown needs 5mA.

[image: optocoupled 8 relay module]

These babies switch up to 30A at 5 to 24V. I used to make this sort of module myself but it's cheaper to buy them complete.

Another thing you might look at depending on how much current you need to switch, is MOSFETs instead of relays. High input impedance, low trigger current and very fast switching with no bounce. You do get a bit of forward leakage. You can drive em straight off the ESP IO pins.

Comment: Just verify if "isolation" is well done for the AC power side! Some are not. Especially for 240 Vac.

Comment: These are low voltage DC units. But that's _always_ sound advice. For _that_ kind of application frankly I'd do a destruction test for isolation breakdown voltage, and measure heat dissipation under load because melted insulation is way too exciting with serious power.