Why are my relays heating?
I am using an ESP32 development kit with a 5V eight relay block. Following this answer, I removed jumper JD-VCC and powered the  relay block at the JD-VCC pins from an external 5V 2A adaptor. The relay IN pins are directly connected to ESP32 pins. gnd -> gnd and VCC of relay ->3v3 of the ESP32. The relays are heating. Is that normal? Is there any solution to prevent heating?
This is my test code:
Refer: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/505318/how-to-properly-use-a-relay-module-with-jd-vcc-from-arduino-raspberry
*/
 
#define role1Penye 2        //klemens1
#define role2bld 4          //k2
#define role3bld 13         //k3  
#define role4wtc 25         //k4
#define role5hrm 21         //k6
#define role6inverter 22    //k7
#define role7hrm 16         //k9
#define role8hrm 17         //k10

int roles[] = { role1Penye, role2bld, role3bld, role4wtc, role5hrm, role6inverter, role7hrm, role8hrm };
int numRoles = sizeof(roles) / sizeof(roles[0]);

void setup() {
  // put your setup code here, to run once: 
  for (int i = 0; i < numRoles; i++) {
    pinMode(roles[i], OUTPUT);
    digitalWrite(roles[i], HIGH);
  }


  pinMode(14, OUTPUT);  //  bug
}

void loop() {
  // put your main code here, to run repeatedly:

  for (int i = 0; i < numRoles; i++) {
    pinMode(roles[i], OUTPUT);
    digitalWrite(roles[i], LOW);
    delay(30000);
  }

  for (int i = 0; i < numRoles; i++) {
    pinMode(roles[i], OUTPUT);
    digitalWrite(roles[i], HIGH);
    delay(30000);
  }
}


This is my relay module:


The Relays can't both be heating "too much" and "normally". If it's normal it's not too much and vice versa.

I consider it bad practice to write source code in non-english. Be that as it may, when asking questions about the code on an international q/a site where working language is English, I'd suggest translating the comments so it's possible to follow the thought process.

@MrGerber thanks I ve updated

Relays are active components, they will heat up when driven. As you have not given any information about which relays you are driving we can't know the relay coil nominal power, and as such it's hard to know how hot to expect them to get

"My relay's photo has been added."

If all the relays are all on, do they warm up more or less evenly ? Is there any difference when the relays are powering a device or not ?  As well as the coils, the contacts, if these have a too high resistance, can contribute to the warming effect.

THIS IS IMPORTANT !  1. What is your load per relay =- voltage and current. Are the relays heating due to the switched current or the coil power? | 2 If you turn them all on with no load then the heat is what you'd normally expect. || IF they get much hotter when they are switching load current then they are probably not suited to the task. || Are they "Songle" brand relays. One photos shows Songle & one doesn't. || Based on my experience Songle relays are cheap junk. Using them to switch mains voltages OR currents approaching their claiomed ratings will quite likely lead top disaster.

Answer questions in my answer and question can be reopened. - Please flag for reopening once answered. These answers are vital to understanding your  requirement.

NOTE The close vote reason given by the system is rubbish. This question can be reopened once requested information is provided. It is very important that we understand what is causing the heating (it's very likely the contact dissipation) and we need to know what voltage and load are being switched.

Do you have any update on the source of heating? This is easy to test. Power / operate the relays with no load applied - do they get too hot after say 10 minutes of continuous power being applied. Now apply power and load and power the relays again. Does the load current cause most of the heating?  How hot do they get? (Just able to be touched continually is about 45 degrees C. Too hot to touch is hotter than that. Hisses when a wet cloth or wet finger is applied is over 100 degrees C - FAR too hot.

THIS IS IMPORTANT !



What is your load per relay - voltage and current.




Are the relays heating due to the switched current or the coil power?



If you turn them all on with no load then the heat is what you'd normally expect.
IF they get much hotter when they are switching load current then they are probably not suited to the task.
Are they "Songle" brand relays?
One photo shows Songle brand & one doesn't.
Based on my experience Songle relays are cheap junk.
Using them to switch mains voltages OR currents approaching their claimed ratings will quite likely lead to disaster.

I will change relay and test again

The relays heat up because when turned on, each coil draws about 72mA at 5V, or 0.36 watts.
Thus 8 relays heat up at 2.88W.
